# Typing very slow in TINY MCE editor

Tags: tinymce

I have large data of content (newsletter) and I have added in Tiny Mce Editor. Contents looks fine but when I start typing (adding more content) it types very slow and I have to wait until it's done printing the character.

The issue is with large contents only not with small content.

You can check below demo link to test the above case. Paste the large content it source code and try to type in Tiny Mce editor not in source code.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/basic-example/

Comment: Without a concrete example of what you are putting in TinyMCE nobody will be able to provide you much help.  A term like "large content" is relative and won't help anyone to diagnose your issue.  Can you make a TinyMCE Fiddle or JS Fiddle that shows what is happening?  A minimal, complete, verifiable example would be incredibly helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i faced similar issue. My problem was that in tinymce.init i had a function for update textarea:

```
setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {
            tinymce.triggerSave();
        });
    }
```

Problem was that the function update textarea with every change, with every key press or color change. More content, more slower.

My solution here was simple, delete triggerSave from tinyMCE init and call tinymce.triggerSave() right before submitting form via submitting button:

```
<button type="submit" name="btn-addpost" onclick="tinyMCE.triggerSave();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>&nbsp; Add Post</button>
```

Maybe you have similar problem.

I hope this will be in any way helpfull for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using TineMce with React js and facing the same problem. The problem was on every key press inside editor I was updating the form value which was causing the slow typing.

So instead of updating form on every key press I am updating at onBlur event now.

Below is my example for React js but you just have to implement **onBlur** event in your js code

```
const handleEditorBlur = (ed, event) => {
    const content = event.getContent();
    if (content) {
        formik.setFieldTouched("content", true);
    }
    formik.setFieldValue("content", content);
}

<Editor
    apiKey={process.env.MIX_TINYMCE_API_KEY}
    onBlur={handleEditorBlur}
    //onEditorChange={handleEditorChange}
    //value={formik.values.content}
    init={{
        content_css: "writer",
        plugins: "lists",
        toolbar: "code",
    }}
/>
```